# How to find api action path from another action

Tags: api, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

In My Reserve `ApiController`, I need to have may BankRedirect action's path in a string and `Url.Route` has been used but it doesn't work.

```
 public string GoToBank(string token, string username )
        {
            string path Url.Route("BankRedirect", new { controller = "Reserve"} , new { userId = "" }))

            return path;
        }



 [Route("BankRedirect")]
        [HttpPost]
        [BasicAuthenticationFilter]
        public async Task<UpdateResult<string>> BankRedirect( [FromBody]string userId)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The corresponded path for decorating action with `[Route("BankRedirect")]` is `/BankRedirect`ץ

The given `Url.Route` output is `Reserve/BankRedirect`.

`/BankRedirect` !=  `Reserve/BankRedirect`

You should change one of them, either:

```
[Route("Reserve/BankRedirect")]
```

Or

```
return "BankRedirect";
```

Comment: "Reserve" is the route of my controller -- [RoutePrefix("Reserve")]
    public class ReserveController : ApiController